# How to everything but number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a `dict` like so: `dic = {80:90, 7:60, 9:1}` then I converted the dict into a list `li = [dic.keys()]` but when I print I get `[dict_keys(['80, 7, 9'])]`.

How do I remove everything but `'80, 7, 9'`?

Comment: try `li = list(dic.keys())` if you want the keys as a list (as opposed to a 1-element list whose sole item is an iterable)

Comment: The described rationale for closing seems wrong -- the problem seems more one of not being able to get the keys into a list (rather than in not being able to print the list, though the latter seems like it is likely a problem for them as well).

Comment: 1. Please indicate which Python version you're reffering to. From mentioned output I assume your question is related to Python 3.

2. Also the final question is not well stated. You can remove everything but `'80, 7, 9'` parsing the final output or changing the `li` conversion code. Assuming the latter and a **conversion** keyword, the answer is to use `list` constructor directly to perform the conversion: `li = list(dic.keys())`.

Reason? `[]` brackets put an item into the list, that's why you have a nested list here. See also Python 2, where your `li` is displayed as `[[80, 9, 7]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
li = dic.keys()
```

keys() already returns a list of the keys in your dictionary.

Comment: The question clearly involves Python 3 (based on the output that they describe). Your answer is only true of Python 2. Python 3 is much more lazy -- it only produces a list in a case like this if you force it to by using `list()`

Comment: No wonder I despise Python 3. Thanks though.